# SAS gz a file when importing

Tags: sas, pipe

I am trying to import a file 'filename.csv.gz' into SAS.
Currently, I am trying to gunzip

```
FILENAME in PIPE "gunzip -dc filename.csv.gz" LRECL=80 ;
```

I am getting these errors:

```
ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access PIPE.
ERROR: Error in the FILENAME statement.
```

I am trying to figure out a way around the PIPE and I cannot manually do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your SAS admin has disabled the ability to run operating system commands from SAS, so the PIPE engine does not work.

But you don't need the PIPE engine to read a gzipped file. Use the ZIP engine instead with the GZIP option.

```
FILENAME in zip "filename.csv.gz" gzip LRECL=80 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need OPTIONS XCMD; which may not be permitted.  Can you run your program in BATCH?

https://support.sas.com/kb/15/179.html